# What are these undocumented arguments for register_taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, codex, register-taxonomy

The Wordpress codex has an example of the `register_taxonomy()` function at http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies that shows arguments that are not documented in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy.

In particular `args['sort']` and `args['args'][order_by]`.

What's the story with these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the Taxonomies Codex entry is simply out of date.

[Per source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L0), there are no `'sort'` or `'orderby'` args for `register_taxonomy()`.

Given the purpose of the `register_taxonomy()` function, it doesn't even really make *sense* for this function to include sort/orderby parameters. Such parameters would be relevant to *listing* taxonomy terms, not to *registering* the taxonomy itself.